# How to build nock regex for dynamic urls

Tags: node.js, api, nock

How do i build nock configuration for the following types of urls

```
http://example.com/harry/potter?param1=value1
```

and

```
http://example.com/harry/<value1>
```

I have two type of urls first is where i can have query params altough the base url is fixed.

Second one is where base url has dynamic values.

Currently i have

```
before(function(){
   nock('http://example.com')
       .get('/terminal/chrome_log')
       .reply(200, "OK");

  nock('http://example.com')
       .get(function(uri) {
           return uri.indexOf('harry') >= 0;
       })
        .reply(200, "OK");
    });
```

Would be of great help to know something that works with node nock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify [path and query as reqex](https://github.com/node-nock/nock#specifying-path):

```
  nock('http://example.com')
       .get(/harry\/[^\/]+$/)
       .query({param1: 'value'})
       .reply(200, "OK");
```