# Regex matching for nock tests failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, nock

I am trying to match URLs.

```
lab.before(async () => {
  nock('https://dev.azure.com')
    .get(centosAzureUri)
    .times(5)
    .reply(201, [
    ...
```

If I use a string, it is working just fine. An example is below:

`` const centosAzureUri = `/${conf.org}/${conf.buildProject}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1&branchName=${conf.buildBranch}` ``

However, I want to use a RegEx as below:

`` const centosAzureUri = new RegExp(`/${conf.org}/${conf.buildProject}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1.*`, 'g') ``

That is not working.

According to the documentation, `nock` should accept regular expressions and `.*` should match any symbol [because of the .] and allow those matched characters to be repeated any number of times. Hence, I am assuming this should accept any string ending, including `&branchName=${conf.buildBranch}`.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think nock only uses regex literal vs. regex object which will return a new object.  eg.

```
  nock('http://example.com')
       .get(/harry\/[^\/]+$/)
       .query({param1: 'value'})
       .reply(200, "OK");
```

See related
[How to build nock regex for dynamic urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47599884/how-to-build-nock-regex-for-dynamic-urls)

Comment: Thank you. Literals are working. Personally, I did not see anything either written nor in the `nock` code that would prevent RegEx objects from working. In the meantime, followed your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that RegExp only needs the pattern up to "4.1" to perform a match. The rest of the string will be ignored if the match occurs. For example:

```
const centosAzureUri = new RegExp(`/${conf.org}/${conf.buildProject}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1`, 'g')
```

Further, you may want to try escapements, since slashes require those:

```
const centosAzureUri = new RegExp(`\/${conf.org}\/${conf.buildProject}\/_apis\/build\/builds?api-version=4.1`, 'g')
```

HTH!